# Performing operations only on subset of a RDD

Tags: apache-spark

I would like to perform some transformations only on a subset of a RDD (to make experimenting in REPL faster).

Is it possible?

RDD has `take(num: Int): Array[T]` method, I think I'd need something similar, but returning RDD[T]

Comment: is your question still open? If you have an acceptable answer, don't forget to mark it as such.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You can use `RDD.sample` to get an `RDD` out, not an `Array`. For example, to sample ~1% without replacement:

```
val data = ...
data.count
...
res1: Long = 18066983

val sample = data.sample(false, 0.01, System.currentTimeMillis().toInt)
sample.count
...
res3: Long = 180190
```

The third parameter is a seed, and is thankfully optional in the next Spark version.

Answer (score 3):

`RDD`s are distributed collections which are materialized on actions only. It is not possible to *truncate* your `RDD` to a fixed size, and still get an `RDD` back (hence `RDD.take(n)` returns an `Array[T]`, just like `collect`)

I you want to get similarly sized `RDD`s regardless of the input size, you can truncate items in each of your partitions - this way you can better control the absolute number of items in resulting `RDD`. Size of the resulting `RDD` will depend on spark parallelism.

An example from `spark-shell`:

```
import org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
val numberOfPartitions = 1000

val millionRdd: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000000, numberOfPartitions)

val millionRddTruncated: RDD[Int] = rdd.mapPartitions(_.take(10))

val billionRddTruncated: RDD[Int] = sc.parallelize(1 to 1000000000, numberOfPartitions).mapPartitions(_.take(10))

millionRdd.count          // 1000000
millionRddTruncated.count // 10000 = 10 item * 1000 partitions
billionRddTruncated.count // 10000 = 10 item * 1000 partitions
```

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it's possible to create RDD subset by first using its `take` method and then passing returned array to SparkContext's `makeRDD[T](seq: Seq[T], numSlices: Int = defaultParallelism)` which returns new RDD.

This approach seems dodgy to me though. Is there a nicer way?

Answer (score 0):

I always use [parallelize](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/core/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext) function of SparkContext  to distribute from Array[T] but it seems makeRDD do the same. It's correct way both of them.